# Explain why I get: warning assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe program, but I have run into a warning. I know that the code still compiles, but I want to know why I have this warning and what I  can do to fix it.

I get the warning when p = a;

```
void clean(){
    char a[N][N], *p;
    p = a;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            *p++ = '_';
        }
    }
    display(a);
}
void display(char a[N][N]){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%c ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `p` is of type `char *` while `a` after decay become pointer of type `char (*)[N]`.

Comment: you'd put each variable declaration on separated line ;)

Comment: An array is not a pointer. Typically the compiler will not just say "waring: something is wrong", but provide a more exact reason. See [ask] and follow the advice!

Comment: Note that `clean()` is trying to clear and display a local array which will be forgotten on function return.

Comment: @WeatherVane: OP does not provide enough context and does not return the array. We have no idea what he intends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clean` function should be this:

```
void clean(void){
    char a[N][N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            a[i][j] = '_';
        }
    }
    display(a);
}
```

There is absolutely no advantage of having the `p` pointer, except that your code is less readable.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, you are right, but the question wasn't dealing with that aspect.

Comment: `void clean()` is a deprecated (since 17 years) old-style signature. It should be prototype-style `void clean(void)`.

Comment: Michael I have moved that comment to the main question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Okay thank you, but the reason I thought I would use a pointer instead of just the array is that when the user puts a 'x' in a[2][2] it would update by changing the pointer value. Any tips on how I could do this with out without pointers

Comment: @Jackvile didn't quite understand what you mean by  _it would update by changing the pointer value_.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, but don't I need to set a[N][N] = "_" into a pointer so that it remembers that they are _. I want the array a[N][N] to remember that they are all intilitzed to '_'

Comment: @Jackvile if you don't want to set `a[N][N]` to = `_` then what should `clean` do ??

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well once one use wins or stalemates, clean() will reset the board and the new game can began all over

Comment: @Jackvile so you _need_ to set every cell to `_` (?!). Sorrry I don't get it, your statements are somewhat contradictory.

Comment: It's hardcore optimization and worthless in most circumstances but in general using a pointer like that to raster scan the array will actually save a multiplication and an add. Though the best way would be to determine an end-point and scan the whole array as a single run.

Answer (score -1):

a[][] is an array of n char, therefore &a is a pointer to an array of N,N chars. 
This is not compatible with a pointer to a single char,as p is a pointer to a char 
Jst the explanation

Comment: `&a` is a `char (*)[5][5]`, i.e. a pointer to a 2D array, not a `char (*)[5]`. `int *` is even worse, as it has not even to correct base-type.

Comment: `a [5][5]` is not an array of "5 `char`s".